# Django form to display user attributes

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I'm having an odd problem that I can't remedy: Django is not displaying any of the user's attributes except for the username when using a form that includes a foreign key attribute between two models.

The associated username is showing up correctly, but none of the other attributes are (first name, last name, email, etc).

Similarly, the debugging print statement that I've placed in the views.py is correctly printing the user's attributes in the terminal output.

Why aren't any of the user's attributes showing up in the html template?

**models.py**

```
class UnitGroup(models.Model):
    unit_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Unit Name')

class UnitUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(UnitGroup)
    ROLES = ((0, 'Admin'), (1, 'Member'))
    role = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Role', choices=ROLES)

    def __string__(self):
        return self.user.first_name
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UnitUser
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
from units.forms import UnitForm, UnitDetailsForm, UserGroupForm
from units.models import UnitGroup, UnitDetails, UnitUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def edit_members(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated() \
            and request.method == 'GET' \
            and 'unit' in request.GET:

        unit_group = request.GET['unit']
        unit_users = UnitUser.objects.filter(unit=unit_group)
        unit_forms = []

        for i in unit_users:

            # debug
            print(i.user.first_name)
            print(i.user.last_name)

            unit_forms.append(UserGroupForm(instance=i))

        return render(request, 'units/edit-members.html', {'unit_forms': unit_forms})
```

**edit-members.html**

```
{% for form in unit_forms %}

    user: {{ form.user }} <br>
    first name: {{ form.user.first_name }}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UserGroupForm is a model-form, based on the UnitUser model. 
The fields of the form are based on the fields of the model.

Since UnitUser doesn't contain details about the user, but merely a single reference to the user model, the user model itself is only represented via a single field. The string representation of a user model is the username. I would think that's the reason you see the username in your form.

In short: Your model-form considers the user just as a single field and will use the string representation of the value of that field as init-value.

If you want to display further attributes of the user in your form, you might have to construct a specific form for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking that it was passing the actual objects and not a string representation. I got around this by ditching the model form and passing the model values into a form on the web page, then passing the results back into a model object in views.py. A bit more work obviously, but it does the job.